# R missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed

Tags: r, function, if-statement, variables, syntax

I have an error on my R script: `missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`.
The only `IF` condition that I have on my is:

```
 layer_dense(units = layer_one_nb_node, activation = layer_one_activation, input_shape = c(15)) %>%
        layer_dropout(rate = layer_one_dropout/10)
      if (layer_two_nb_node != 0){
        layer_dense(ann,units = layer_two_nb_node, activation = layer_two_activation) %>%
          layer_dropout(rate = layer_two_dropout/10) 
      }
      if (layer_three_nb_node != 0){
        layer_dense(ann,units = layer_three_nb_node, activation = layer_three_activation) %>%
          layer_dropout(rate = layer_three_dropout/10) 
      }
      if (layer_four_nb_node != 0){
        layer_dense(ann,units = layer_four_nb_node, activation = layer_four_activation) %>%
          layer_dropout(rate = layer_four_dropout/10)
      }
      if (layer_five_nb_node != 0){
        layer_dense(ann,units = layer_five_nb_node, activation = layer_five_activation) %>%
          layer_dropout(rate = layer_five_dropout/10)
      }
      layer_dense(ann,units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')
```

I changed it to `layer_five_nb_node != 0` to `!is.na(layer_two_nb_node)` But I still have the same error. Any idea ?

```
ann <- keras_model_sequential()
  ann %>%
    layer_dense(units = layer_one_nb_node, activation = layer_one_activation, input_shape = c(15)) %>%
    layer_dropout(rate = layer_one_dropout/10)
  if (!is.na(layer_two_nb_node)){
    layer_dense(ann,units = layer_two_nb_node, activation = layer_two_activation) %>%
      layer_dropout(rate = layer_two_dropout/10) 
  }
  if (!is.na(layer_three_nb_node)){
    layer_dense(ann,units = layer_three_nb_node, activation = layer_three_activation) %>%
      layer_dropout(rate = layer_three_dropout/10) 
  }
  if (!is.na(layer_four_nb_node)){
    layer_dense(ann,units = layer_four_nb_node, activation = layer_four_activation) %>%
      layer_dropout(rate = layer_four_dropout/10)
  }
  if (!is.na(layer_five_nb_node)){
    layer_dense(ann,units = layer_five_nb_node, activation = layer_five_activation) %>%
      layer_dropout(rate = layer_five_dropout/10)
  }
  layer_dense(ann,units = 2, activation = 'sigmoid')
```

Comment: One of the functions you're using may have an `if()` condition throwing this error - use `traceback()` after the error to see if it's inside another function.

Comment: Hi Gregor, unfortunately,  `traceback()` returns me: `No traceback available`

Comment: Well, you need to isolate the problem. You still get the same problem after changing these if statements to `if (!is.na(layer_two_nb_node))`, therefore these if statements are not the problem. Run chunks of your code until you can find the line causing the problem.

Comment: Thx for the tips. I am working with PSO package, I think the issue is coming from the package, coz the error is: `Error in while (stats.iter < p.maxit && stats.feval < p.maxf && error >  : 
  missing value where TRUE/FALSE needed`